# Finding the partial sums of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I've tried to find the partial sums of this infinite series in order to get the series sum result:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right )\cos\left (\frac{1}{2^n}\right )$$

Can anyone show me the steps please .. thanks

Comment: Hint: $\sin(a)\cos(a) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2a)$.

Comment: Do you want to find the exact value of the sum, or just show convergence?  The second is (as usual) much easier.

Comment: I want the steps and the exact value :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible... unless someone gets some amazing telescoping series.

Comment: The value according to wolframalpha is 0.9

Comment: Not the exact value though.

Comment: Yeah, the value is approximately $0.908964$.  If the exact value were $.9$ there might be some reason to suspect a nice closed form exists, but as it appears to be some arbitrary real number I don't have any reason to suspect a closed form exists.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1938554/335418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is only meant to approximate the solution.

Notice that

$$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

So your sum can be reduced to

$$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(2^{1-n})=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})$$

Notice then that for all $n\ge0$ that $\sin(2^{-n})<2^{-n}$ so that

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})&=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sin(2^{-n})+\sum_{n=k}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})\\&<\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sin(2^{-n})+\sum_{n=k}^\infty2^{-n}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sin(2^{-n})+2^{1-k}\end{align}$$

Thus, you can quickly approximate the solution.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})&<\sin(1)+1\approx1.841470985\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})&<\sin(1)+\sin(1/2)+1/2\approx1.820896523\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})&<\sin(1)+\sin(1/2)+\sin(1/4)+1/4\approx1.818300483\end{align}$$

If one takes this all the way, to say, $k=10$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^{-n})\approx1.817928721$$

Thus, half of this is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right )\cos\left (\frac{1}{2^n}\right )\approx0.908964361$$